# How do you re-ask someone else's question when the existing answers do not work for you?

Tags: discussion, bounties, duplicate-questions

I have a problem with GitHub Pages, whereby a very simple site (in [here](https://github.com/githubpagestest83/githubpagestest83.github.io)) gives a 404 Not Found error. I have tried all eighteen (!) solutions suggested in the different answers to [How to fix page 404 on Github Page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11577147/575530).

Starting a bounty on a question with 18 existing answers (many of which solved the problem for others experiencing the same issue) seems odd, but re-asking the same question also seems wrong. What is the correct thing to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may ask a new question referring to the existing one, and clearly state why none of the answers given there solves your problem.

> I have tried all eighteen (!) solutions

Best show what problems you face when you try to apply the answers to your particular problem.

Comment: Done, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55314621/575530).